# removeAllFeatures + destroyFeatures too much?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm doing the following in my code and am wondering if it's too much or is there any benefit?

```
        myLayer.removeAllFeatures();
        myLayer.destroyFeatures();
```

Reference:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.removeAllFeatures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy and paste from the OpenLayers mailing list:

> ... removeFeatures removes the
> feature from the layer (and from the
> feature array) but the features aren't
> destroyed, for example they can later
> be added back to the layer. After
> removeFeatures the layer has no
> references on the layers, user code is
> therefore responsible for destroying
> the features and releasing references
> so that the features are
> garbage-collected. After
> destroyFeatures the features are
> removed from the layer and destroyed.
> Like after removeFeatures they
> shouldn't reappear on the layer after
> redraw, if you observe otherwise it's
> certainly a bug that we need to track
> down. ...
>
> http://www.mail-archive.com/users@openlayers.org/msg04868.html